# R plot expot with actual size

Tags: image, r, plot

I'm new in R coding, so I need help or advise. 
I'm building plot based on coordinates (originally this is eye tracking data). I`m exporting just dots without any axes or text. Later I will have to compare this dots with Image at which person was looking at.

So my aim is 1) to have exported image with very specific size (same to original image) and without any distortion (it seems to appear after manual entering of sizes in export dialog window). 2) to have this plot exported without extrafields, that obviously appers at every side.

Thank you in advance

UPD i`m thinking now if there is any way to move point of zero to left bottom corner of image? I was trying to work my problem out with cutting margins: par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), xaxs='i', yaxs='i'), but it seems to cut all the empty parts of image. And I want to stay potentially working parts safe and keep size and proportions.

that is my source code

```
    card1 <- "D:/01_experiment/02.04/p02/card1.txt" 
    table01 <- read.table(card1, strip.white = TRUE, sep="\t", header = TRUE)

    jpeg('card81.jpg', 
         width = 842, 
         height = 595)

    par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), xaxs='i', yaxs='i')

    plot(x = table01[,10], 
         y = table01[,11], 

         pch=20,
         type="o",

         #xaxt='n',
         yaxt='n',
         ann=FALSE,

         bty="n",
         xlab = "desity.x",
         ylab = "desity.y"
         )
    dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
library(grid)

pdf("points.pdf", width=5, height=3)
grid.points(x <- runif(10), y <- runif(10), vp=dataViewport(x, y, extension = 0))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: if the 'extension = 0' fixes the scale?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean; please clarify your question

Comment: Sorry, I`ve tried to figure out what part of code cut axes, and then realized, that you used grid, not plot. My bad, don`t keep in mind. Would you please read my update in message?

Comment: sorry but even after the update I still have no idea what you want to do. Please provide example data and a precise description of what you want to be displayed in your plot.

Comment: I`m sorry for being so messy. Basically  I have picture, at which person is looking. Eye-tracker writes his eyes-movement, so my data is coordinates x and y. I`m building a plot and then want to overlay it to the source image, to at what points person was looking more. So I`m trying to export this picture without any extra fields - just all working area, that matches original image.

Comment: i`ve tried it once again after 'clear all', and it worked perfectly. thank you a lot!